# How to resolve Crash while runing pipiline job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, crash-reports

I have some strange crash while i try to run script in Jenkins

The regex work good I checked the output while the job run the regex return the good value

why i have crash while i run code with regex, and why all work good if I add the value as string?

When i try run this code as is i have a crash

```
def pattern = ~/(https:.*\d+)/
def temp = logforParce =~ pattern
def link = temp[0][1]
pattern = ~/(\/-?\d+)/
temp = link =~ pattern 
def product = temp[0][1] //"/819421"
withCredentials([usernamePassword(usernameVariable: 'USER', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD', credentialsId: '16650710-c58f-43df-95b7-dd27052e55ac')])
{
bat """ 
"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin\\curl.exe" -u $USER:$PASSWORD -k -X GET https://sever.com/api/product$product/pdf-report --output "%PATH%\\BDBA\\report.pdf"
"""
}
```

In this case I have  this Crash

```
Error when executing always post condition:
an exception which occurred:
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@71b3b65e
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosureDef.capture
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosureDef@5c0d9a7e
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosure.def
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@42e4cdf4
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@36d25232
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@36d25232
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:926)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1793)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor228.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:156)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:191)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1028)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1793)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor228.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:156)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:191)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1028)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.lambda$writeObject$0(RiverWriter.java:144)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:237)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:143)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:557)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:534)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:517)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:441)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:136)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timeout
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timestamps
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
an exception which occurred:
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@71b3b65e
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosureDef.capture
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosureDef@5c0d9a7e
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosure.def
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@42e4cdf4
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@36d25232
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@36d25232
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:926)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1793)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor228.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:156)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:191)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1028)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1793)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor228.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:156)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:191)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1028)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.lambda$writeObject$0(RiverWriter.java:144)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:237)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:143)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:557)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:534)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:517)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:441)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:136)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

But if i add the value that i get from Regex manualy. All work good.

```
def product = "/819421"
withCredentials([usernamePassword(usernameVariable: 'USER', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD', credentialsId: '16650710-c58f-43df-95b7-dd27052e55ac')])
{
bat """ 
"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin\\curl.exe" -u $USER:$PASSWORD -k -X GET https://server.com/api/product$product/pdf-report --output "%PATH%\\BDBA\\report.pdf"
"""
}
```

Comment: Common pitfall. Look at https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/. Assigning `null` can also solve your problem: `pattern = null`

Comment: Thanks @MaratC  I solved the problem in another way. I just divided parsing and command for two different steps and it work perfect. With null it was the same crash. Only in two different stages the pipeline start work without crash

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem with divide string parsing and running the batch command for two different steps.